# Application of Sturm comparison theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $w(x), q(x)$ be continuous functions on $[a,b]$ and $q(x) < 0, \forall x \in [a,b].$ Could anyone advise me how to use Sturm comparison thm to show any non trivial solution to $y^{\prime\prime} + w(x)y' +q(x)y$ has at most one zero in $[a,b] \ ?$ I also tried to use Mean Value theorem to no avail.

Thank you.